# Input type=number Safari still allows letters with stepper

Tags: html, google-chrome, input, safari

I have an **input field** which only allows number:

```html
<input class="border" type="number" numeric step="0.1" inputmode="numeric" digitOnly maxlength="6" formControlName="resultInput" pattern="[0-9]+"/>
```

I set more parameters than needed just to check if it would work with these. Unluckily it didn't.
When I am using it on **Chrome** it works, but when I am using it on **Safari** it doesn't.

Comment: What version of Safari? I just tested your code snippet in Safari Version 13.0.4 and it worked.

Comment: I have the same version checked it with "mdls -name kMDItemVersion /Applications/Safari.app", but it is not working.

Comment: Step 1: [Clear the browser cache](https://fabricdigital.co.nz/blog/how-to-hard-refresh-your-browser-and-clear-cache). Step 2: Profit?

Comment: Nope, still not working as I wanted it.

Comment: Which attributes aren't working? Is it just `maxlength`?

Comment: It is not about `max length`, it is about `type="number"`. It should be enough to only allow numbers, but unfortunately it still allows letters. I added the other parameters to check if they help me, but they are not working as `type="number"`.

Comment: I edited your post to use the stack snippets feature. Are you seeing the same 
behavior here on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Thanks for editing @MarcBarbeau, didn't know that feature exists. Unfortunately I do see the same behaviour here on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Did you end up solving this?

Comment: Unfortunately not but upvoting maybe helps to solve it. @AbdulAziz

Comment: FYI, still broken in Safari 16.2 and FireFox 108.0.1 even with all the above options.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, many browsers will only validate the input for an `input` with `type="number"` upon form submission. In such a case, the following prompt will appear (example from Safari):

[image: Safari input field prompting the entering of a numeric value.]

I've modified your snippet to remove any non-numeric input as it is entered. I have tested that this snippet works on the Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

```html
<input class="border" type="number" numeric step="0.1" inputmode="numeric" digitOnly maxlength="6" formControlName="resultInput" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*?)\..*/g, '$1').replace(/^0[^.]/, '0');" />
```

If you were willing to forgo the stepper, you could avoid having a single non-numerical character remove the entire input:

```html
<input class="border" type="text" inputmode="numeric" digitOnly maxlength="6" formControlName="resultInput" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*?)\..*/g, '$1').replace(/^0[^.]/, '0');" />
```

In these snippets, we use:

```html
oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*?)\..*/g, '$1').replace(/^0[^.]/, '0');"
```

to remove all characters that would result in the value in the `input` not matching a typical numeric form (no leading zeroes, no more than one decimal point).

Be warned: while you can use HTML, CSS and JavaScript to restrict what users enter when using your website normally (known as 'client-side validation'), it is trivial to bypass the restrictions set this way.

If you are sending this data to a server for transformation, you should not trust that this data will only be numeric and of the form you expect. You should consider this type of validation to be **purely for convenience's sake** rather than providing any guarantee that the server will receive valid data.

Comment: Firstly thanks for your contribution. Is there any way to work with the stepper and not reset the whole input by a non numerical input?

Comment: I've experimented for a while and not been able to find a working solution. I think some combination of `oninput` and `type="numeric"` prevents this from working correctly. I'd advise that if you want input fields that behave similarly across browsers and platforms, it may be worth looking into a web development framework where you can design input fields from the ground up. The various implementations of HTML and CSS vary too widely by platform in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

The above series of "replace" did not work for me. Since my project is in Angular, I instead created a custom form field validator. That way, an error is presented to the user on invalid input (which prevents form submission):

```
public static numberInputValidator(min: number, max: number): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
    if (isUndefinedOrEmpty(control?.value) || control.value <= min) {
      return { numberRequired: true };
    } else if(control.value > max) {
      return { numberTooBig: true };
    }
    return null;
  };
}
```

The only related attributes on the HTML input field are: `type="number" step=".01"`

To use it, add the validator to your FormControl in your FormGroup:

```
myControlName: new FormControl<undefined | number>(undefined, numberInputValidator(0, 100))
```

And even though the validator takes only `number` inputs, it will return `numberRequired` if the form field contains non-numeric characters.

You can then display custom error messages as such this (right after the `<input>` field) if using Angular Material form fields:

```
  <mat-error *ngIf="vm.formGroup.get('myControlName')?.errors?.numberRequired">
    <p>Amount must be greater than zero</p>
  </mat-error>
  <mat-error *ngIf="vm.formGroup.get('myControlName')?.errors?.numberTooBig">
    <p>Amount must be less than or equal to 100</p>
  </mat-error>
```